# How can I save multiple items to an array field when creating a new record in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schema that is used for a "Groups" collection. I want to be able to create this record and push an arbitrary number of "members" to this group when it is first created. I am unable to get the "members" field to populate when I save the record. All other fields are saved without a problem.

```
var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    creator : String,
    name : String,
    members: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    created : {
        type: Date,
       default: Date.now
    }
});

app.post('/create-group', function(req, res) {
    //req.body.users = ['12345', '23456', '34567'] for example
    var group = new Group({
        name : req.body.group_name,
        creator : req.user._id,
        members: {$push: req.body.users}
    });
    group.save(function (err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

No results are ever stored in "members", even though all other fields are saved correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

In your schema when you wrote ref :"User" it means that you have to provide a User schema and not a string or integer. If you just want an array of string you can simply use [String].

According to the doc you have to use an objectID http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
```

In the link provided above you will be able to check how to save your group and adding an arbitrary number of members.

Comment: Yes, the contents of ``req.body.users`` are object ids. I just used those numbers as placeholders so I wouldn't have to write out a bunch of long object ids.

Comment: no you use a string instead of an ObjectId -- >  members: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'User'
    }], . All of what you are trying to do is described in the link I provided. You are doing it the wrong don't know where did you catch your example but it's better to follow the doc when you can.

Comment: Okay, just to be very clear. ``req.body.users`` is an array with values such as "53e81a945e9af400007178rd", etc. Also, I know how to populate the members objects when doing a find. I just don't know how to properly save elements to the members field. The save code I have above doesn't work, and that's where the problem is.

Comment: did you check the link I provided ?

Comment: Yes, I've been to that link many times before. I was a great resource when I needed to find out how to populate the "members" field.

Comment: Ok on this exact same link you can also learn how to "saving refs". That's what I did and it's working fine. PS : don't forget the part "Refs to children" if you want to be able to populate your array of members

Answer (score 0):

```
members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
```

As Su4p has pointed out. Don't worry about `req.body.users` containing strings instead of ObjectIds. `mongoose` will cast the strings into objectIDs.
There's also another mistake,

```
        members: {$push: req.body.users}
```

should be

```
        members: req.body.users
```

`$push` is an update operator. It's not meant for assigning arrays.